# apply style on button click angular2

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have HTML as follows,

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" (click) aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="flag">
    </span>Spain <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul  class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
```

On click of the above button i want to apply the following style,

```
.dropdown-menu
{
display :block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically put an ng class and set variable value on the button click.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" (click)="toggle = !toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="flag"></span> Spain <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
      <ul  class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" [ngClass]="{'blockStyle': toggle == true>

.blockStyle{
display :block;
  }
```

Comment: idea is to set a variable trigger the ngClass to apply the block style on the element. try to move the click to a function in your .ts file and console log use chrome is it setting the values and enabling the class on that element.
don't forget put the class in your css file.